# Top header cart modification

Tags: magento-2.1, header, mini-cart

[image]

How to remove edit and remove buttons/links from the top header cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these contents are presents in

`app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

`app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html`

it is implementation of html and knockout js combination so you can easily found above mentioned button and link.

for remove button/link, you can override from theme like

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `product actions` **div** under in  `default.html` given path below:

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```