# Magento 2: How to override Item Info of MiniCart

Tags: magento2, overrides, custom, mini-cart, magento2.1.5

I would like to override Item Info of Mini Cart here as well as on Checkout Sidebar

I need to apply changes on price. Which files need to override & function?

[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/148121/36463

Comment: Hi @BilalUsean Display files i know. I need the PHP function from where it's coming. So can override that info